# How to design table which have variable quantity of attribute in database?

Tags: database, database-design, web, database-schema

For example, I want to store the shopping list for each day.

If I write a db table like:

```
Date Item1 Item2 ... Item100
```

Obviously, this will leave many slots empty and we have a limited number. How can I store this?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, in rows, not in columns...

Comment: @fancyPants What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

Table orders:

```
order_id | customer_id | created_at | other_info_you_need | ...
     1         1          yesterday        whatever
     2         1            today          whatever
```

Table items:

```
maybe_an_auto_increment_column | order_id | item     | how_many
              1                      1      thing_a       1
              2                      1      thing_b      10
              3                      2      thing_c       2
```

For a detailed answer on why there's not enough room here. Read up about [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and database design in general.

Comment: As you may disagree, I am wondering how Normalization will help this. Since "Date Item1 Item2 ... Item100" conforms to 5NF, we choose Date as primary key. I think your "Table items" does not conform to 3NF, (order_id, items) -> how_many.

Comment: Yes, I disagree. But again, I will not write a book for you here, there's plenty of information about database design on the net already. Your table is not 5NF and the relation between my 2 tables is a simple 1:n relation. It's 3NF...Don't worry, if you would have understood normalization in such short time just by reading a wikipedia article, I would have pulled my hat.

Comment: Thanks, but just curious. Why my table isn't 5NF(I may not be clear I only make an entry a day and ignoring the amount so date will be the primary key)? And I think since order_id and item are also candidate key, so they won't violate 3NF.